# Symfony Query Builder: string with special characters

Tags: php, string, symfony, utf-8, query-builder

I've done a simple Query:

```
        $users = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

In my table I have some names with non-ascii characters like 'Stéphane' or 'Aurélien'.

When I output my names, I have this:

```
["name"]=> string(17) "AurĂŠlien"
```

or

```
["name"]=> string(16) "StĂŠphane"
```

How can I have the correct UTF-8 characters ?

Comment: Can you check encoding of your database?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database's & table's **collation** is  ***utf8_unicode_ci*** & if it's different then change it to **utf8_unicode_ci**

Here you can see the [effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-effect.html)